# Parse Facebook Login not working on all devices

Tags: facebook, xcode5, parse-platform

I am fairly new to Parse but it has been really helping my app get to where it needs to be. I am running into a problem that I can't seem to get around. So I have a login with facebook button and it worked fine on my device. The user was added to my parse data browser and dev facebook account no problem, but when I tried to run it on my co-workers device I'm hit with this ugly error.

Uh oh. An error occurred: Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.)" UserInfo=0x176b55d0 {com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason=com.facebook.sdk:SystemLoginError, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorInnerErrorKey=Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 "The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: Invalid application 528878730564765" UserInfo=0x176a5d60 {NSLocalizedDescription=The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: Invalid application 528878730564765}, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=, expirationDate: (null), refreshDate: (null), attemptedRefreshDate: 0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(null)>}

Any suggestions? If you need any more information on my code please just ask. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you taken your app out of sandbox mode on facebook? Otherwise, fb will only allow access to developers and test accounts with express authorization.  You could also have your coworker set up for a developer account and add him to your approved list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In FB developer page for your app, have you made sure that either your coworker's fb account is added here:

[image]

Or, take your app public to allow all FB profiles here:

[image]